# Php make column wise array from an existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to make an array as column from another array which representing like below. the column should be individual based on each index like , custom_text, thumb and title. I did more favor below.

```
array(6) {
[0]=>
array(1) {
["custom_text"]=>
string(15) "custom text 1"
}
[1]=>
array(1) {
 ["custom_text"]=>
string(18) "custom text 2"
}
[2]=>
array(1) {
["thumb"]=>
string(59) "image 1"
}
[3]=>
array(1) {
["thumb"]=>
string(59) "image 2"
}
[4]=>
array(1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(51) "title 1"
}
[5]=>
array(1) {
["title"]=>
string(181) "title 2"
 }
```

}

here below code is for the array output

```
    $th = array();
    $allrows = array();
   
    foreach($aawp_table['rows'] as $table_row_id => $table_row ){
        if ( ! $table_row['status'] )
            continue;
       $th[] = array('headings' => $table_row['label']);
       foreach ($aawp_table['products'] as $table_product_id => $table_product){
           $asin = $aawp_table['products'][$table_product_id]['asin'];
           $data = $aawp_table['products'][$table_product_id]['rows'][$table_row_id];
           $type = $aawp_table['rows'][$table_row_id]['type'];
           if ( 'custom_text' === $type ) {
                   $allrows[] = array(
                           'custom_text' => 'custom text'
                   );
           }
           if ( 'thumb' === $type ) {
               $allrows[] = array(
                   'thumb' => 'thumb'
               );
           }
           if('title' === $type){
               $allrows[] = array(
                   'title' => 'title'
               );
           }
       }
    }
       echo '<pre>';
      
       var_dump($allrows);
      
       echo '</pre>';
```

I want the array out like this as individual column

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
string() "custom text 1"
[1]=>
string() "image 1"
[2]=>
string() "custom text 2"
}
```

Can you please help to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
if ( 'custom_text' === $type ) {
               $allrows[] = array(
                       'custom_text' => 'custom text'
               );
       }
       if ( 'thumb' === $type ) {
           $allrows[] = array(
               'thumb' => 'thumb'
           );
       }
       if('title' === $type){
           $allrows[] = array(
               'title' => 'title'
           );
       }
```

You should do this

```
if($type === 'title' || $type === 'thumb' || $type === 'custom_text'){
array_push($allrows,$type);
}
```

Comment: but based on types the index should have different value how you do this?

Comment: My answer will generate the array as you required. However, if you required different values then you can use your code for separate values for each index just add array_push($allrows,'value you want to assign'); instead of these $allrows[] = array(
               'title' => 'title'
           );

Comment: I think what @mdkamrul needs is mapping, so that all related values are together, please correct me if I'm wrong. Now, it needs a bit more details for better solution. so the questions are:
- are you going to have have same number of elements from all different arrays (i.e. if you have 5 custom_text, then are you going to have 5 'thumb' and 'title' as well?).

Comment: - if it is, then do they come in same order? (i.e. custom_text[3] can have thumb[3] and title[3]?

- are you planning to get more array elements later on?

Answer (score 0):

Let's iterate over the array you have and get all values for resulting array. Something like that.

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'custom_text' => 'custom text 1',
    ],
    [
        'custom_text' => 'custom text 2',
    ],
    [
        'thumb' => 'image 1',
    ],
    [
        'thumb' => 'image 2',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title 1',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'title 2',
    ],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $outterArray) {
    foreach ($outterArray as $innerArrayValue) {
        $result[] = $innerArrayValue;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

The code snippet would generate the following output.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "custom text 1"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "custom text 2"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "image 1"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "image 2"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "title 1"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "title 2"
}
```

Comment: please check my expected output at my question

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following the logic behind the output.